# Ubuntu 16.04.04 LTS -> Active-Backup Bond not working with IPv6

Tags: 16.04, networking, ipv6, network-bonding

I have setup a server that has a Bonded connection.

IPv4 works great, but for some reason IPv6 is not working at all.

I can't even ping the router.

I saw this was a known issue on https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1280362

Which has a much better write up, but has anyone found a fix for this?

Comment: If anyone had found a fix for it, it would have been in that launchpad entry, and would have been fixed, and would have been in an update for Ubuntu.

Comment: Not necessarily, LTS doesn't get updates right away, unless you want to install them manually.

And just because one website doesn't have the answer, doesn't mean the answer isn't out there.

Comment: Do you understand that the page you linked is the official Ubuntu bug report for that issue? Your comment seems to imply that you do not.

Comment: I'm saying that because it is an official a bug report, it needs an official fix, but doesn't mean there isn't workaround... Unless those don't exist anymore.